# i want to store each rdd into database in twitter streaming using apache spark but got error of task not serialize in scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, twitter

I write a code in which twitter streaming take a `rdd` of tweet class and store each `rdd` in database but it got error task not serialize I paste the code.

`sparkstreaming.scala`

```scala
case class Tweet(id: Long, source: String, content: String, retweet: Boolean, authName: String, username: String, url: String, authId: Long, language: String)

trait SparkStreaming extends Connector {

  def startStream(appName: String, master: String): StreamingContext = {
    val db = connector("localhost", "rmongo", "rmongo", "pass")
    val dbcrud = new DBCrud(db, "table1")
    val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master).set(" spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    //  .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "HelloKryoRegistrator")
    //    sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[DBCrud]))
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
    ssc
  }
}
object SparkStreaming extends SparkStreaming
```

I use this streaming context in plat controller to store tweets in database but it throws exception. I'm using *mongodb* to store it.

```scala
def streamstart = Action {
    val stream = SparkStreaming
    val a = stream.startStream("ss", "local[2]")
    val db = connector("localhost", "rmongo", "rmongo", "pass")
    val dbcrud = DBCrud
    val twitterauth = new TwitterClient().tweetCredantials()
    val tweetDstream = TwitterUtils.createStream(a, Option(twitterauth.getAuthorization))
    val tweets = tweetDstream.filter { x => x.getUser.getLang == "en" }.map { x => Tweet(x.getId, x.getSource, x.getText, x.isRetweet(), x.getUser.getName, x.getUser.getScreenName, x.getUser.getURL, x.getUser.getId, x.getUser.getLang) }
    //  tweets.foreachRDD { x => x.foreach { x => dbcrud.insert(x) } }
    tweets.saveAsTextFiles("/home/knoldus/sentiment project/spark services/tweets/tweets")
    //    val s=new BirdTweet() 
    //    s.hastag(a.sparkContext)
    a.start()
    Ok("start streaming")
  }
```

When make a single of streaming which take tweets and use `forEachRDD` to store each tweet then it works but if I use it from outside it doesn't work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create connection with **MongoDB** inside `foreachRDD` block, as mentioned in [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)

```
tweets.foreachRDD { x => 
 x.foreach { x => 
  val db = connector("localhost", "rmongo", "rmongo", "pass")
  val dbcrud = new DBCrud(db, "table1")
  dbcrud.insert(x) 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it later on but if its work but i have question for each partition of RDD we need to open connection to database ??

Comment: The [version 2.0.2 of documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) states that opening a connection for every record is a common mistake. Instead, `rdd.foreachPartition` should be used.